# Azure functions - When do we need to use out for output bindings?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-queues

In azure functions there is multiple ways to do output bindings.

1. For Blob storage, I can declare it as a binding with no additional constructs.
2. For CosmosDb , I need to specify it as an out parameter.
3. For a queue ,I can specify it as  return in the attribute.

I have a sample code below for the above three scenarios

```
 public static class myblobtestfunc
    {
        [FunctionName("myblobtestfunc")]
        [return: Queue("samplequeue", Connection = "storageconnection")]
        public static string Run([BlobTrigger("functiontestblob/{name}.txt", Connection = "storageconnection")]Stream myBlob,
                               [Blob("copyblob/{name}", FileAccess.Write)]Stream copyBlob,
                               [CosmosDB(databaseName: "testfiledb", collectionName: "testfilecoll", ConnectionStringSetting = "cosmosdbconnectionstring")]out dynamic document,
                               string name,
                               ILogger log
                               )
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            myBlob.CopyTo(copyBlob);
            
            document = new { Description = name, id = Guid.NewGuid() };

            return name;
        }
    }
```

Can output bindings use any of the three ways to do it? i.e. Can I use the return with CosmoDb binding?
Why have such a wide choice of output binding styles?

Comment: You cant use the return in a method signature anyway. This code isn't valid. As to why you can do things more than one way? well because its convenient

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral. Makes Sense but binding expressions and the several ways of returning data while convenient, introduces an additional element to think through especially out and non out binding parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Can output bindings use any of the three ways to do it? i.e. Can I use
> the return with CosmoDb binding? Why have such a wide choice of output
> binding styles?

Such a wide choice of output binding styles comes from the support ticket continuously launched by the Azure function community.

In fact, for specific output binding, these three are not necessarily all feasible. Please refer to official doc. The designs of these three are based on the corresponding SDK package, so in most cases, it is equivalent to writing the code based on corresponding SDK in the function body.